# sudo jq query permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, jq

Im trying to use jq to alter a json file via a script.

in my terminal im trying to run this, but getting a permission denied error. Im able to change it using a sudo nano manually.

```
sudo jq -c  '.interpreterSettings."2ANGGHHMQ"."properties"."zeppelin.pyspark.python" = "python3"' interpreter.json > tmp.$$.json && mv tmp.$$.json interpreter.json
```

Any ideas on why?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: For your convenience, [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2024).

Answer (score -3):

Simple fix, just gave user permissions on directory.

sudo chmod -R 777 /etc/zeppelin/conf

Comment: Granting global write and execute to a conf file is almost always the wrong thing.